# Can you make "offline" ssd with grub

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, multi-boot, grub, dualboot

I have an SSD with Ubuntu where GRUB is located (I think it should be there because I installed grub when I was on Ubuntu). I also have nvme ssd with Windows, and another hdd used by that windows as a storage. My whole partition system is kind of a mess because I ran boot repair utility after installing Windows on my nvme ssd (because the old grub installation got broken after that, you can check [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1755371/boot-repair-aftermath) for more details if you want because it's still wasn't answered, I would appreciate if someone will answer it too), but this time the question is another:

I turned off my HDD on Windows disk management utility (pressed "go offline" on that HDD) because I don't use it that often, so I'm hoping to save some power by turning it off. Can I do the same with my SSD? I'm asking because when I'm loading I'm choosing Windows from grub, and I think that GRUB is located on the Ubuntu SSD (because it's also the first option in UEFI). Will turning it off while I'm on Windows break anything, if I already logged into Windows? Thanks in advance.

If it helps, I can make a screenshot with my disks partitions if it's needed, just tell me what to run and screen.

Comment: @Ramhound, what if there's EFI partition on my windows ssd too? Idk which is being used tho

Comment: @Arzybek Why do you feel putting your SSD and HDD offline will save power? The power required for an SSD and an HDD are minimal at best. Just because you can make a device go offline doesn’t mean it is actually useful for all cases and conditions. You might actually put your devices at more risk when powering them up and down all the time. Better just let the system manage that instead of doing that manually.

Comment: @Arzybek - Are there actually two EFI partitions, that would be a strange and very unusual setup? If the EFI is on the drive you want to disable and is being used by Windows, then my comment still applies. You have not given anyone enough information to answer your question truly.

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't call `two EFI partitions` a `strange and very unusual setup`, especially not when they are on different disks and for different OS.

Comment: @TomYan - That’s why I wanted the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it won't cause any problem. The "offline" setting in Disk Management applies only to the *running* Windows. It will NOT stop your UEFI firmware from being able to execute grub or even the Windows Boot Manager. It basicially means to unmount and avoid mounting any (Windows) filesystems / volumes on the drive so that no filesystem level access will be allowed (but lower level access like block level access and SCSI level access will still be available AFAIK, so you could still potentially wipe / overwrite the drive with certain applications even when a drive is offline). It might be worth mentioning that you are required to set the drive to offline when you SCSI passthrough it to a Hyper-V VM. (I don't know if you still need to do it manually or Hyper-V will do it dynamically / automatically for you.)

The only case that I could think of in which it could cause problem is that Windows shares the EFI system partition on that Linux drive. In that case it can prevent e.g. Windows Updates from making necessary changes to the BCD or so. But then I *suspect* Windows will not allow you set the drive offline in that case.

I myself would disable drive (or even the "controller", like in the case of NVMe or USB) in Device Manager instead (of course I mean when "offline" is fine), although it's way easier to have the wrong drive/device disabled there. That would in turn prevent essentially (or literally?) all access to the drive. (AFAIK, literally you need to enable it back before you get access to it on any level.) That *might* work better as well if it's about powering. (I'm not going to bother either judging or endorsing whether it could do you any good or harm in terms of powering.)

P.S. Note that "mounting" mentioned above is probably not the same thing as `mount` in `mountvol`. AFAIK `mountvol` is similar or perhaps equivalent to assigning a drive letter with e.g. `diskpart`. But AFAIK, at least in special case like the EFI system partition, a filesystem is still "mounted" (in the sense that filesystem level access can be performed "behind the scene") even when a volume has no drive letter assigned.

Comment: You can run `bcdedit` to find out the HarddiskVolumeN of the EFI system partition Windows uses / is booted from, and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1386685) might be the easiest way for you to find out which drive HarddiskVolumeN belongs to.